# Apply function to NA matrix in R

Tags: regex, r, function, apply

I want to use the apply to use a function that I used to pull data via regular expressions and fill a matrix with it.

```
planetdata = function(dline) {
  new_line = unlist(strsplit(as.character(dline),"</td><td>"))
  new_first_value = substring(new_line[1],9)
  new_last_value =substring(new_line[11],1,nchar(new_line[11])-10) 
  new_line[1] <- new_first_value
  new_line[11] <- new_last_value 
  new_data <- new_line
  return(new_data)

}


new.dt = dt[21:1912]
exo.mat = matrix(data = NA, nrow=1892, ncol = 11)
colnames(exo.mat) <- c(exo.col.names)
apply(exo.mat,2,function(new.dt) planetdata(new.dt))
```

However, my matrix does not change and all the values are still NA. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: It is better to show few lnes of `dt`.  A small reproducible example and expected output is good.  From the code, it seems like you created a `NA` matrix, and loop through the columns, apply the `planetdata` on the the whole dataset `new.dt`, I am not following the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this? `exo.mat[] <- apply(new.dt, 2, planetdata)`

R usually passes by value, not by reference. Modifying a variable inside a function will generally not modify it outside. You need to save the value out explicitly.

Also, you were passing in the empty matrix to `apply()`, it just didn't look that way because you made an anonymous function with a `new.dt` parameter, which is different from the `new.dt` variable you had in your session.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion, but it simply gave me matrix that started inserting values in the first column and simply worked its way down by column rather than from left to right by each row. Is there syntax on how to do that?

Comment: `apply` will always return by column-major ordering. You could transpose the matrix, eg `t(X)`.